# ZipFile does not store any text inside an archived file

Tags: python, python-zipfile

The following code results in the file found in the zip being empty, instead of having `some text` in it:

```
def func(path):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        f.write('some text')
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            zf.write((f.name), path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flush` to the file object:

```
def func(path):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        f.write('some text')
        f.flush()  # <-- lifesaver
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            zf.write((f.name), path)
```

This problem also affects normal (non-temporary) files, so they'll also need the `flush` treatment:

```
def func(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('some text')
        f.flush()  # <-- lifesaver
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            zf.write(path)
```

Alternatively, de-denting the 2nd `with` block would avoid having to use `flush` since a file gets closed automatically when that block exits, increasing the chance of it being flushed:

```
def func(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('some text')
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        zf.write(path)
```

Note that this will only work for the 2nd example, but not the 1st; see [tempfile docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) for the reason why.

Comment: Alternately, you could close the file. In your case, you could dedent the second with clause so that the first one exits and closes the file.

Comment: De-denting for the first example would not work, unless I were to ask `NamedTemporaryFile` not to delete the file, which would defeat my purpose for using it.